# Is there a place to find a list of good premium/paid drupal modules?

Tags: 9

I have a client that has "deep pockets" and so higher ups are pushing for us to use premium modules so that "the user experience is better for the client". I haven't ever used a premium/paid drupal module and haven't been able to find a place where I can see a list of them to see if any would be beneficial (specifically higher ups are looking for premium calendar and hero banner modules).

Any one know of where to find options like those (assuming they are available)?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I see a lot of questions getting shut down because they are asking for recommendations for a module that will do x,y,z - Where are people supposed to ask those questions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the higher-ups have confused Drupal with WordPress.  Drupal has very few paid modules; most of the ones I know of are related to simplifying OAuth login (sign in with Apple/Google/Facebook, etc.), which is a site-specific need.

There are some paid themes, but these are generally less than $100 and often not a "premium" experience because the default Drupal theme of Olivero is far more extensively tested and has greater browser compatibility and accessibility support than the "premium" themes.  If a company really wants theming done right, they will hire someone skilled to do a custom theme.

This is true for custom modules more generally-- it would be very difficult in Drupal to do a great "paid" module because it would have to compete with a free module that does the same thing, but is more widely used and thus gets more bug reports and is better tested.  However, it may be that the current modules do not support a feature they want.  Some module maintainers will accept sponsorship to add features.

So, if there is money to spend, consider suggesting investing in Drupal by sponsoring the development of a module or feature that provides whatever feature the company needs that doesn't already exist.  This way, everyone using Drupal can benefit in the same way that the company benefits from using Drupal.